# Are app store ratings visible globally?

Tags: ios, app-store, rating-system

If I review an app on the USA Apple App Store, I understand that the review only shows up on the USA store. Does the star rating system also stay localized? If someone rates an app on the Chinese store, is that rating reflected globally in the ratings average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it s localized. If someone rate your app in Chinese store, only chinese will see it, the comments too.